# How to register Angular HttpInterceptor for submodule only

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am having a problem with registering HttpInterceptor for submodule in Angular 7 application. My intention is that only requests performed from a submodule are intercepted and adjusted. The code of an interceptor is as follows.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {from, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor
{
  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
  {
    return from(this.authService.get()).pipe
    (

      switchMap(authData =>
      {
        const headers = request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authData.jwtAccessToken);
        const requestClone = request.clone({headers});
        return next.handle(requestClone);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

it gets registered in one of the submodules

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {DemandDetailComponent} from "./demand-detail/demand-detail.component";
import {DemandService} from "./services/demand.service";
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from "@angular/common/http";
import {TradingRoutingModule} from "./trading-routing.module";
import {AuthInterceptor} from "../core/interceptors/http.interceptor";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DemandDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TradingRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    DemandDetailComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DemandService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class TradingModule { }
```

Interceptor uses inside an `AuthService`, which is created as follows

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthData} from "../model/authData";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private authData : Promise<AuthData>;

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient)
  {
  }

  initialize()
  {
    this.authData = this.httpClient.get<AuthData>([auth-data-endpoint]).toPromise();
  }

  get()
  {
    return this.authData;
  }
}
```

And is initialized in app compontent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ConfigurationService} from "./core/services/configuration.service";
import {AuthService} from "./core/services/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor (private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private  authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configurationService.initialize();
    this.authService.initialize();
  }
}
```

For some reason, initialization call of authService is gets intercepted, what makes an app to fail as the authService is not yet initialized. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP interceptor should be set when importing core module (so in your case in app.module.ts I assume), otherwise it will not work mainly because HTTPClientModule is already started when you try to set the interceptor.

For more detailled explanation check [Angular: When HttpInterceptor doesn’t work with lazy loaded modules](https://dev.to/devakone/angular-when-httpinterceptor-doesn-t-work-with-lazy-loaded-modules-3ipg)